# what's the difference between the properties fallback and blockhandler of @SentinelResource

Tags: java, spring-boot

When I use @SentinelResource as below:

```
@SentinelResource(value="test_sentinel",fallback="sentinelFallbackHandlerTest",blockHandler="sentinelBlockHandlerTest",exceptionToTrace=BlockException.class)
```

Then I configured the rules in the sentinel-dashboard, and I found out that when the rule was triggered, the blockhandler method will be executed.

I'd like to know that under what conditions fallback method will be executed. As the sentinel docs described, fallback will handle the exception throwed by the method with @SentinelResource. So I write the code:

```
int a = 1/0;
```

in the method, but fallback method has not been executed.

So, I'd like to know when the fallback method and the blockhandler method will be executed ? And  what's the difference between the properties fallback and blockhandler of @SentinelResource ?